# Splitting rows of a dataset depending on a column values

Tags: apache-spark

I am using `Spark 3.1.1` along with `JAVA 8`, i am trying to split a `dataset<Row>` according to values of one of its numerical columns (greater or lesser than a threshold), the split is possible only if some string column values of the rows are identical : i am trying something like this :

```
                Iterator<Row> iter2 = partition.toLocalIterator();                   
                while (iter2.hasNext()) {
                    Row item = iter2.next();
                      //getColVal is a function that gets the value given a column
                    String numValue = getColVal(item, dim);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(numValue) < threshold)    
                        pl.add(item);  
                    else
                        pr.add(item);
```

But how to check, beforehand splitting, if some other column values (string) of the concerned rows are identical  in order to perform the split ?

PS : i tried to groupBy the columns before splitting like so :

```
Dataset<Row> newDataset=oldDataset.groupBy("col1","col4").agg(col("col1"));
```

but it's not working

Thank you for the help

EDIT :

A sample dataset which i want to split is :

```
abc,9,40,A
abc,7,50,A
cde,4,20,B
cde,3,25,B
```

If the threshold is `30` then the two first and last rows will form two datasets because the first and fourth columns of these are identical; otherwise the split is not possible.

EDIT : the resulting outpout would be

```
    abc,9,40,A
    abc,7,50,A


    cde,4,20,B
    cde,3,25,B
```

Comment: if I'm understanding correctly, are you looking to get 2 datasets if the threshold of col3 is > 30. Could you also add what the resulting dataset would look like? Also , if your threshold isn't met, could you provide an example output?

Comment: Yes exactly 2 datasets if the threshold of col3 is > 30, if threshold is not met just return the original dataset

Comment: check my edit for the example output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mainly use `pyspark` but you could adapt to your environment

```
## could add some conditional logic or just always output 2 data frames where 
##   one would be empty

print("pdf - two dataframe")
## create pandas dataframe
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['abc','abc','cde','cde'],'col2':[9,7,4,3],'col3':[40,50,20,25],'col4':['A','A','B','B']})
print( pdf )

## move it to spark
print("sdf")
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf) 

sdf.show()
# +----+----+----+----+
# |col1|col2|col3|col4|
# +----+----+----+----+
# | abc|   9|  40|   A|
# | abc|   7|  50|   A|
# | cde|   4|  20|   B|
# | cde|   3|  25|   B|
# +----+----+----+----+




## filter
pl = sdf.filter('col3 <= 30')\
        .groupBy("col1","col4").agg(F.sum('col2').alias('sumC2'))
pr = sdf.filter('col3 > 30')\
        .groupBy("col1","col4").agg(F.sum('col2').alias('sumC2'))
print("pl")
pl.show()
# +----+----+-----+
# |col1|col4|sumC2|
# +----+----+-----+
# | cde|   B|    7|
# +----+----+-----+


print("pr")
pr.show()
# +----+----+-----+
# |col1|col4|sumC2|
# +----+----+-----+
# | abc|   A|   16|
# +----+----+-----+


print("pdf - one dataframe")
## create pandas dataframe
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['abc','abc','cde','cde'],'col2':[9,7,4,3],'col3':[11,29,20,25],'col4':['A','A','B','B']})
print( pdf )

## move it to spark
print("sdf")
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf) 
sdf.show()
# +----+----+----+----+
# |col1|col2|col3|col4|
# +----+----+----+----+
# | abc|   9|  11|   A|
# | abc|   7|  29|   A|
# | cde|   4|  20|   B|
# | cde|   3|  25|   B|
# +----+----+----+----+



pl = sdf.filter('col3 <= 30')\
        .groupBy("col1","col4").agg( F.sum('col2').alias('sumC2') )
pr = sdf.filter('col3 > 30')\
        .groupBy("col1","col4").agg(F.sum('col2').alias('sumC2'))

print("pl")
pl.show()
# +----+----+-----+
# |col1|col4|sumC2|
# +----+----+-----+
# | abc|   A|   16|
# | cde|   B|    7|
# +----+----+-----+

print("pr")
pr.show()
# +----+----+-----+
# |col1|col4|sumC2|
# +----+----+-----+
# +----+----+-----+
```

Filtering by a dynamic mean

```
print("pdf - filter by mean")
## create pandas dataframe
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['abc','abc','cde','cde'],'col2':[9,7,4,3],'col3':[40,50,20,25],'col4':['A','A','B','B']})
print( pdf )

## move it to spark
print("sdf")
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf) 
sdf.show()
# +----+----+----+----+
# |col1|col2|col3|col4|
# +----+----+----+----+
# | abc|   9|  40|   A|
# | abc|   7|  50|   A|
# | cde|   4|  20|   B|
# | cde|   3|  25|   B|
# +----+----+----+----+

w = Window.partitionBy("col1").orderBy("col2")
## add another column, the mean of col2 partitioned by col1
sdf = sdf.withColumn('mean_c2', F.mean('col2').over(w))

## filter by the dynamic mean
pr = sdf.filter('col2 > mean_c2')
pr.show()

# +----+----+----+----+-------+
# |col1|col2|col3|col4|mean_c2|
# +----+----+----+----+-------+
# | cde|   4|  20|   B|    3.5|
# | abc|   9|  40|   A|    8.0|
# +----+----+----+----+-------+
```

Comment: Could you explain these lines `pl = sdf.filter('col3 <= 30')\
        .groupBy("col1","col4").agg(F.sum('col2').alias('sumC2'))
pr = sdf.filter('col3 > 30')\
        .groupBy("col1","col4").agg(F.sum('col2').alias('sumC2'))` In JAVA if possible

Comment: Sure, 
`pl = sdf.filter('col3 <= 30')\         .groupBy("col1","col4").agg(F.sum('col2').alias('sumC2'))`

set `pl` to where col3 values are less than 30. Group by columns `col1,col4` and sum column2 and alias to `sumC2`

If you're only looking to split into 2 dataframes then you would only need
`pl = sdf.filter('col3 <= 30')`
`pr = sdf.filter('col3  > 30')`

the .agg is if further aggregation is needed post filtering

Comment: found this https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset/filter

` JavaDataFrameSuite.testExecution() `
`@Test`
`public void testExecution() {`
` Dataset<Row> df = spark.table("testData").filter("key = 1");`
` Assert.assertEquals(1, df.select("key").collectAsList().get(0).get(0));`
`}`

Comment: OK for select will act as a filter and will be something like `.select("col3 > threshold")` but `collectAsList().get(0).get(0));` will serve for what ?

Comment: i am trying something like this : `Dataset<Row> filteredDF = dF.filter("col2 > 60").groupBy("col0","col1","col3").agg();` but don't know what to put in `agg()`

Comment: What are you looking to aggregate? If you don't need any aggregations, you can remove `.groupBy("col0","col1","col3").agg()`

Comment: Alright, I have one more question : could we discuss it in chat ?

Comment: Actually i want to filter a dataset by its column values (values over the mean and under the mean) i need something like this dynamically calculating the mean `df.filter("col2 >"+ mean(col2))` is it possible ?